# How to debug in-process hosted ASP.Net Core apps with WinDBG and SOS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windbg, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 app, targeted to .Net Core 2.2. I host it on Azure App Service using the new [in-process hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
Then I create a memory dump via App Service diagnostic tools. Open it using Visual Studio, and I see two CLR versions: 4.7.3190.0; 4.6.27110.4. I can tell that 4.7.3190.0 is for .Net Framework, and 4.6.27110.4 is for .Net Core.
[image]
If I open the dump in WinDBG, it keeps loading the mscordacwks DLL for 4.7.3190.0. I have no way to make it load the mscordaccore DLL for 4.6.27110.4. And thus a simple SOS command such as `!Threads` leads to error `Failed to request ThreadStore`.

How can I debug my managed code (the .Net Core part) using WinDBG and SOS?

You can get the sample memory dump [here](https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/zhiliangxu/DebugAspNetCore/master/RD0003FF588DD0_w3wp_7900.dmp).

### Update

Thanks for the GREAT help from [Thomas Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-weller)! The solution to this case is to run `.cordll -u -I coreclr -l -lp "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\"`. I must unload (`-u`) CLR DAC and load (`-l`) the **Core** CLR DAC in one command.

The successful commands and logs are [here](https://github.com/zhiliangxu/DebugAspNetCore/blob/master/success.log).

Comment: You should disable ASP.NET 4.x for your App Service, to remove .NET Framework noises. .NET Core debugging should follow initial steps like https://bret.codes/net-core-and-windbg/

Comment: @LexLi: Could you teach me how to disable ASP.NET 4.x for my App Service? I can only choose from 3.5 and 4.7 in the portal, but am not able to disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I would say, have a look at the [`.cordll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-cordll--control-clr-debugging-) command. Specifically,

```
0:000> .cordll -u
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
```

to unload the CLR DAC and

```
0:000> .cordll -I coreclr -l -lp "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\"
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL f:\debug\symbols\mscordaccore_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.27110.04.dll\5BE756335c6000\mscordaccore_AMD64_AMD64_4.6.27110.04.dll
```

to load the .NET Core DAC from a specific path.

---

In your crash dump, there are 2 CLR versions:

```
0:000> lm m *clr
start             end                 module name
00007ffc`ac990000 00007ffc`acf56000   coreclr    (deferred)             
00007ffc`c2130000 00007ffc`c2b1d000   clr        (deferred)
```

The details are

```
0:000> lmvm clr
[...]
    File version:     4.7.3190.0
0:000> lmvm coreclr
[...]
    File version:     4.6.27110.4
```

Just as shown by Visual Studio.

If you do the usual `.loadby sos clr`, it will load SOS for the 4.7 version from where `clr` is. Unfortunately, `.loadby sos coreclr` will not work the same way, because the debugging support is not delivered for .NET Core in the same way it is for .NET.

```
0:000> .loadby sos coreclr
The call to LoadLibrary(D:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\sos) failed
Win32 error 0n126 "The specified module could not be found."
```

If you have installed the matching .NET Core package, there are some SOS versions in a path like `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\`. You can then load the extension from that path explicitly:

```
0:000> .load C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\sos.dll
```

Make sure you unload the SOS of CLR:

```
0:000> .unload C:\...\sos.dll
```

And check with `.chain` that only one SOS is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. But could you share mode detail about `.cordll -u -l -lp`? I ran `.cordll -u -l -lp "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0"`, and got
`CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll\5B693B489ed000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll`.
And `!Threads` still returns `Failed to request ThreadStore`.

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work. Here are the console logs.
`0:000> .unload`
    
`Unloading MexOMStub extension DLL`
    
`0:000> .cordll -u -l -lp "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0"`
    
`CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll\5B693B489ed000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll`

Comment: It seems that the new WinDbg (engine version 10.0.18309.1000) keeps loading `mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll`.

Comment: I've put the output of `.chain` [here](https://github.com/zhiliangxu/DebugAspNetCore/blob/master/.chain.log).

Comment: Even after I explicitly run `.unload MexOMStub` `.unload DbgEngCoreDMExt`, `.unload C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll\5B693B489ed000\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll` and `.load C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\sos.dll`, `.chain` returns [this](https://github.com/zhiliangxu/DebugAspNetCore/blob/master/.chain.2.log), `.cordll` still returns `CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll\5B693B489ed000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.7.3190.00.dll`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've put the full log [here](https://github.com/zhiliangxu/DebugAspNetCore/blob/master/all.log)

Comment: Thanks so much for keeping helping me debug and provide so much details. I finally succeeded. It seems that running `.cordll -u` will automatically load the SOS of .Net Framework version. So I have to combine the first two commands, like this `.cordll -u -I coreclr -l -lp "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\"`. Now commands like `!Threads` and `~*e !CLRStack` are running like a charm!